# What is the most performant way to do ray-tracing with a surface whose formula is known?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, mesh, raytracing

Ray-tracing with meshes of triangles has widely known solutions and a plenty of resources. There is a related problem which involves ray-tracing for surfaces with known parametric formulas, such as:

```
S(u,v) = (cos(u), sin(u), v)
```

Which represents an unit cylinder aligned to the Z axis. My question is: what is the most efficient way to apply ray tracing to that kind of surface? An obvious solution would be to generate approximate meshes from the formulas and then applying the ray tracing, but my question is if there is a best suited solution for this particular case - specifically by applying some kind of on-demand polynomial solver.

Answer (score 2):

When you mention polynomial solver, this sounds like you'd base things on the implicit algebraic description of the surface. So in your situation, you would get rid of the trigonometric functions using the [tangent half-angle substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution):

```
((1-u^2)/(1+u^2), 2*u/(1+u^2), v)
```

Then you'd turn this into a set of polynomial equations in `x,y,z`:

```
(1-u^2)/(1+u^2) - x = 0
    2*u/(1+u^2) - y = 0
              v - z = 0
```

You could eliminate `u` and `v` from these equations, e.g. using [resultants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

You'd end up with

```
x^2 + y^2 - 1 == 0
```

which comes at no surprise, since that's your cylinder. But the approach above would work for other parametrized surfaces as well. Then you could take your ray of light and, assuming the origin is the camera lens, write a point on that ray as λd where d is the direction of the ray. Plug that point into the equation, solve for λ, find the smallest positive solution and you've got your point where the ray intersects the surface. Furthermore, compute the gradient of the implicit equation at that point and you've got the surface normal as well.

I don't know how far this approach is actually used in practice. Afair most ray tracers are mesh-based for most operations except the most simple of geometric primitives, but this might be outdated information. It would certainly sound a worthwhile approach if you want to avoid CPU-heavy mesh creation and replace it by GPU-heavy high-quality computations of the actual surface.

There are tools, like [Surfer](http://imaginary.org/program/surfer) and its descendants, which have visualizing algebraic surfaces described by implicit equations as their sole purpose. They tend to do a lot of fancy stuff, particularly to deal well with singularities like very thin spikes protruding from such a surface. I've used this tool myself e.g. to illustrate [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1058970/35416). Surfer doesn't have a complex reflection and lighting model, though, so it only does ray casting.